# How JavaScript writes a number with 2 decimal place and it will show 0 in decimal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, numbers, decimalformat

JavaScript writes a number with 2 decimal place and it will show 0 in decimal?

I have no worry about round off the number because I am accepting only 2 decimal place number

```
let num = 2.60
console.log(num) // result 2.6
```

It will return `2.6` but I want `2.60`. I can use `to.Fixed(2)` but it will return in string format.

```
let num = 1.23
console.log(num) // result 1.23
```

I know `to.Fixed()` but it returns string. I want number format and it show `1.00` and `1.60` in number format not in the string format. I have used `parseFloat(num.toFixed(2))` but it does not show last `0` value in decimal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: @David784 all of the answers to that old question are terrible.  The fundamental issue is that JavaScript, like almost all modern mainstream languages, uses a **binary** floating point representation.

Comment: @Pointy yea i agree, the solution to this problem in not in trying to change the number, but rather to have a different variable holding the representation in the format wanted for a certain number

Comment: Simple, you can't. If you want a visual representation keeping the decimal 0's, then you have to use a string, not any number format.

Comment: Leading and trailing zeroes are not part of a binary floating point representation as they have no affect on the actual numeric value.  That's just the way things are.  If you want a certain amount of zeroes to display, then you convert to a string for display purposes and leave the storage as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can never change how the javascript engine represent float numbers, if it is a number and has enough leading zeros that the engine considers that it should cut it then it would do.

`1.60` in floating point is actually more like `1.6000000000000000888`, you can see that yourself by trying

```
console.log(1.60 === 1.6000000000000000888) // true
```

The solution is to use `toFixed` whenever you want to display the value in the format you need, and when you need to do arithmetic operations convert that value back using `parseFloat` - just like you did, but just have separate variables for views and arithmetic.